# Replacing even array elements with zeros in assembler

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, nasm

There is the following problem:
I have  an array, it is necessary to give its size and then in this array for each element that has an even value, assign the value zeros, and return the modified array.

There is my C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            arr[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There is my nasm code:

```
%include "io64.inc"

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
mov DWORD size$[rbp], 10 ; size of array
 
; elements of array
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp], 1
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+4], 2
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+8], 3
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+12], 4
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+16], 5
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+20], 6
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+24], 7
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+28], 8
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+32], 9
mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+36], 10
 

mov DWORD  i$4[rbp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, DWORD  i$4[rbp]
    inc eax
    mov DWORD  i$4[rbp], eax
$LN4@main:
    cmp DWORD  i$4[rbp], 10
    jge SHORT $LN3@main
    movsxd  rax, DWORD  i$4[rbp]
    mov eax, DWORD  arr$[rbp+rax*4]
    cdq
    and eax, 1
    xor eax, edx
    sub eax, edx
    test    eax, eax
    jne SHORT $LN8@main
    movsxd  rax, DWORD  i$4[rbp]
    mov DWORD  arr$[rbp+rax*4], 0
    
$LN8@main:
    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
    
$LN3@main:
    mov DWORD  i$5[rbp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN7@main
    
$LN5@main:
    mov eax, DWORD  i$5[rbp]
    inc eax
    mov DWORD  i$5[rbp], eax
    
$LN7@main:
    cmp DWORD i$5[rbp], 10
    jge SHORT $LN6@main
    
$LN6@main:
    mov edi, eax
    lea rcx, QWORD  [rbp-32]
    mov eax, edi
    lea rsp, QWORD  [rbp+360]
    pop rdi
    pop rbp
ret
```

**My question is: will this code work and how can it be optimized?**

I just get errors like this:

```
C:\Users\79268\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:1: fatal: unable to open include file `io64.inc'
gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\79268\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.o: No such file or directory

C:\Users\79268\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:6: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
C:\Users\79268\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:9: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
C:\Users\79268\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:10: error: comma, colon, decorator or end of line expected after operand
```

So, I install NASM and IDE SASM correctly...

I try to rewrite code and compile it in SASM:

```
section .data
    arr dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10
    
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    call calc
    push arr

calc:
lea rsi, [arr]
mov rcx, [10]
mov rdi, rsi
xor rbx, rbx
@@for:
  lodsq
  test al, 1
  cmovz rax, rbx
  stosq
loop @@for
ret
```

And I get the same error:

```
c:/program files (x86)/sasm/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64
mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64
mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):
crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x25): undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

Now I get the same error for updated code:

```
BITS 64

section .text
    global _start       
_start:  
    push arr
    lea rsi, [arr]
    mov rcx, [10]
    mov rdi, rsi
    xor rbx, rbx
    @@for:
      lodsq
      test al, 1
      cmovz rax, rbx
      stosq
    loop @@for
ret

section .data
    arr dd 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

```
$nasm -f elf *.asm; ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
$demo
/usr/bin/timeout: the monitored command dumped core
sh: line 1: 21184 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/timeout 10s demo
```

Any idea for fix and compile this programm? SASM is nit wirking on my machine, and a try to use this online NASM compilier: [ASM Online compilier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php)

Comment: Just drop the mention `PTR`, but keep the mention `DWORD`. That's how NASM does things as opposed to MASM that does use `PTR`.

Comment: @SepRoland

I try to fix code, but I get a few error and can't compile file in SASM...

Comment: So update your question with the actual errors from the current code.  You don't define an `arr$` symbol anywhere so `error: symbol `arr$' not defined` is expected.  Also, it's weird to put a dollar sign in a symbol name in the first place.  But yes, NASM does surprisingly accept `arr$[rbp]` as an addressing mode, instead of the usual `[arr$ + rbp]` NASM syntax.  I think that changed recently, [in NASM 2.15 for MASM compatibility](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.5).

Comment: Is this MSVC asm output from debug mode?  Use at least some optimization so the code isn't total garbage reloading locals from the stack every use, even `const size`

Comment: @PeterCordes
This output file from debug in MSVC. I try to rewrite this code for NASM and repalce some code elements, but I don't knowe how to compile new code for NASM (I use SASM IDE) on windows. I edit my post and add new code...

Comment: Use a debugger to see which instruction faults.  The time it takes to get a debugger set up and learn to use it will very quickly pay for itself with asm, otherwise you're just wasting your own time (and everyone else's by posting questions without info on which instruction faulted).  In this case, `mov rcx, [10]` loads from absolute address 10 because you put `[]` around it, which isn't mapped, so it segfaults.  That part's a duplicate of [Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/10362511), also you can't `ret` from `_start`; not a function

Comment: If you need a NASM-on-Windows tutorial with the MinGW linker, go look for one that shows you that you have to define a WinMain symbol like the linker told you the CRT startup code was looking for.  I'd guess you might find one with a search for `nasm tutorial WinMain`

Comment: BTW, storing a zero to every other element is a write-only operation.  There's no need to do any loading of old values, or for the store value to be a CMOV result.  (Or to load and re-store the elements you're not touching at all.  Inventing writes to those elements would only make sense if you were using SSE2 to do 16 bytes at a time, using `pand xmm0, xmm1` or something to zero out 2 of the 4 dword elements in a register.)  Also, `stosq` is an 8-byte qword store, not 4-byte dword.